Craft Queue in Laravel Forge: Scheduler or Daemon?
I'm a little confused about the best way to setup server processes using Laravel Forge with Craft CMS (4.8.0).
Currently we are running the following Daemon:
/usr/bin/php /home/forge/domain.com/craft queue/listen --verbose
Should I be running this as a Scheduler instead?
And should runQueueAutomatically be set to false in either case?
The problem with the current setup is the daemon fails and gets backed up quite often. I'm still researching the problem but would love to hear if anyone else has a more hardened solution in a similar scenario as mine.

Without direct access to the Supervisor configuration, the system may be using the default startretries setting, and running out of attempts. The progressive “back-off” may be inadequate to survive intermittent database connectivity issues:

Retries will take increasingly more time depending on the number of subsequent attempts made, adding one second each time.
So if you set startretries=3, supervisord will wait one, two and then three seconds between each restart attempt, for a total of 5 seconds.

(Source)
If you are unable to change this behavior, there is no harm in configuring a second, scheduled queue runner. My recommendation would be to alert Forge of the issue, especially if the underlying services are part of a package configured by their platform.
 Check your logs for evidence that might point to the reason for the exit!

In general, runQueueAutomatically can be disabled when you have a scheduled or daemonized queue runner.

Unfortunately, the issue is more complex. A couple other people (including me) are having the issue where queue jobs stop being processed. The problem is that the daemon doesn't fail or crash, it just stops processing queue jobs. So supervisor doesn't even attempt to restart the service. I've described a workaround (restarting all daemons nightly) here. But still no idea what's causing this. Forge support won't be able to help, as it's likely Craft-specific.
